# Generating subsets of a permutation in Python but not all permutations

Tags: python

I have a list `L = [1,2,3]` and I want to calculate the product of all combinations, but only once -- that is:

```
null # that is, no elements of the list are multiplied
1
2
3
1 * 2
1 * 3
2 * 3
1 * 2 * 3
```

I've seen a number of posts talking about using `itertools`, permutations and combinations, but these return results including `[1,2,3]`, `[2,1,3]`, `[3,2,1]`, etc, which is not what I'm after. (I'm using Python 3 if that is useful to know)

NB Very aware that this could be failure of my search skills, and I just don't know the precise term that I'm looking for.

Comment: It sounds like you want combinations, not permutations. Combinations don't count element order, permutations do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want are all subsets. It turns out [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) offer a neat way to generate the *powerset* of an iterable.

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))
```

#### Example

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul

for values in powerset([1, 2, 3]):
    print(' * '.join([str(x) for x in values]),
          '=',
          reduce(mul, values, 1))
```

#### Output

```
 = 1
1 = 1
2 = 2
3 = 3
1 * 2 = 2
1 * 3 = 3
2 * 3 = 6
1 * 2 * 3 = 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the *powerset* of your set. `itertools` has an example of how to find it.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html